# how to remove the xmlns attribute that gets added after my transformation?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm facing an issue when I transform a json input to an xml output. After transformation i want to remove the **xmlns namespace** before closing tag. These **Namespace** (**xmlns:ind="."** and  **xmlns:att="d"**) need to be removed

**sample input**:

```
{
    "order": "Electronic",
    "productId": 6548790,
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "recieved": "YES",
    "orderId": "12453",
    "desc": "NASQ123",
    "details": [{
        "attributes": [{
            "linetype": "DFU"
        }]  
    }]
}
```

I'm using this below **dataweave script**:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
ns soapenv http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
ns ind .
ns att d
---
{
soapenv#Envelope:{
soapenv#Header: {},
soapenv#Body: {
ind#updateorder: {
ind#orderId: payload.orderId,
ind#orderName: payload.order,
ind#quantity: "5",
ind#order: {
att#productId: payload.productId,
att#desc: payload.desc,
att#shipping: "MAIL",
att#status: payload.status,
att#type1: payload.order,
att#recieved: payload.recieved,
att#otherDetails: payload. *details map ()-> {
att#details1: $.attributeS.linetype,
},
}
}
}
}
}
```

**Current Ouput**:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ind:updateorder xmlns:ind=".">
      <ind:orderId>12453</ind:orderId>
      <ind:orderName>Electronic</ind:orderName>
      <ind:quantity>5</ind:quantity>
      <ind:order>
        <att:productId xmlns:att="d">6548790</att:productId>
        <att:desc xmlns:att="d">NASQ123</att:desc>
        <att:shipping xmlns:att="d">MAIL</att:shipping>
        <att:status xmlns:att="d">COMPLETED</att:status>
        <att:type1 xmlns:att="d">Electronic</att:type1>
        <att:recieved xmlns:att="d">YES</att:recieved>
        <att:otherDetails xmlns:att="d">
          <att:details1/>
        </att:otherDetails>
      </ind:order>
    </ind:updateorder>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, This is my **expected Output After** Transformation is done:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <typ:updateorder>
      <ind:orderId>12453</typ:orderId>
      <ind:orderName>Electronic</typ:orderName>
      <ind:quantity>5</typ:quantity>
      <ind:order>
        <att:productId>6548790</pur:productId>
        <att:desc>NASQ123</pur:desc>
        <att:shipping>MAIL</pur:shipping>
        <att:status>COMPLETED</pur:status>
        <att:type1>NA</pur:type1>
        <att:recieved>YES</pur:recieved>
        <att:otherDetails>
          <pur:details1/>
        </pur:otherDetails>
      </typ:order>
    </typ:updateorder>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Why do you want to output invalid XML?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to get is not a valid XML. Because all name spaces used in an XML needs to be declared within the XML. While writing dataweave, when you add an element like `ind#updateorder` what you mean is "Add an element with name `updateorder` from the namespace `ind`".

If you really want the output without namespace declaration. you can think of it as you need an element with name `ind:updateorder` and not `updateorder` from `ind`.

In other words, replace `ind#updateorder` with `"ind:updateorder"` and similarly at other places. something like this

```js
%dw 2.0
ns soapenv http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
output application/xml  writeDeclaration=false
---
{
  soapenv#Envelope: {
    soapenv#Header: {},
    soapenv#Body: {
      "ind:updateorder": {
        "ind:orderId": payload.orderId,
        "ind:orderName": payload.order,
        "ind:quantity": "5",
        "ind:order": {
          "att:productId": payload.productId,
          "att:desc": payload.desc,
          "att:shipping": "MAIL",
          "att:status": payload.status,
          "att:type1": payload.order,
          "att:recieved": payload.recieved,
          "att:otherDetails": payload.*details map () -> {
            "att:details1": $.attributeS.linetype
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, as I mentioned earlier, **this is not a valid XML**. You can try the [w3school validator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) or any other online tool to validate to check.